# Is it possible to get the bluetooth data from a BT device that is configured for a special app already?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware

I am trying to develop a Continuous Glucose Monitoring (CGM) System.
The CGM consists of 2 parts : A bluetooth sensor that sends glucose measurement reading to the smartphone and An app that recieves the reading from bluetooth and utilizes it further to generate meal plans etc.

The problem I am facing is that I found glucose sensors that send data to their own apps. For example : Dexcom provides a CGM https://www.dexcom.com/continuous-glucose-monitoring Their bluetooth device sends data to their respective smartphone apps i.e Dexcom CGM app. 
Since I am building the software side of the CGM, I would like to have that glucose measurement data from the prebuilt Dexcom device for my own app instead of going to the Dexcom CGM app.
Is there any way to configure the device or configure my software so that it receives the data from Dexcom bluetooth device?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dedicated bluetooth profile  name CGM profile built upon GATT.

The standards of profile and service is available @
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/continuous-glucose-monitoring-profile-1-0-1/
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/continuous-glucose-monitoring-service-1-0-1/
Hope these document helps to realise your implementation